# C) scanf+else+goto

Tags: c, scanf

CODE(this is not my real code. this is exmple)

```
scanf("%d",&a);`

selection:
printf("If you want to go back, press 1, Exit is press 2");
scanf("%d",&a);

if (a == 1)
{}
else if
{}
else
{
   printf("You entered wrong! Try Again");
   goto selection;
}
```

I made a code like this way. But this code repeats at `printf("If you want to go back, press 1, Exit is press 2");` when i enter the letters as mistake. Those 'a' (scanf) is int. I wanna solve this problem ,but I had not figured out. So I need your help!

Comment: Use `fgets()` for user input. Only `fgets()`, always `fgets()`.

Comment: @pmg I respectfully disagree. scanf is a great and versatile tool. Yes, you can first read into a string -- but then you *still* have to parse it, so not much is won (and how would you do that? with sscanf!) It is also often too restrictive to assume input is presented lie by line. That may be true when reading interactive input like here, but even then, inevitably, people come and ask "how can I programmatically ftp" etc.It's better to immediately prepare for the possibility that input may come from a pipe and in different formats.

Answer (score 0):

Store the value returned by scanf (number of read fields) so if scanf didn't read anything, treat it as an invalid input.

```
selection:
printf("If you want to go back, press 1, Exit is press 2");

nf = scanf("%d",&a);

if (nf == 1 && a == 1)
{}
else if (nf == 1 && ....)
{}
else
{
   printf("You entered wrong! Try Again");
   goto selection;
}
```

Comment: Checking the return value of `scanf()` is a good idea! But, unfortunately, won't solve the issue when the user types, for example, `"foo<ENTER>"` because scanf will keep attempting to convert the `f` forever and ever

Comment: @pmg Well, it solves part of the problem. Bu then you still need to read away the bad input.

Comment: @png if working in Windows, fflush(stdin) just before scanf() will throw away all your unparsed input, giving you a clean keyboard buffer.